# how to delete data by id in vue axios

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, vuex

I don't understand why this happened
I display json in the table, and create the delete function.

When I try to delete data in the table, why doesn't the data want to be deleted?
I use postman with the url and id parameter data removed in the database

this my code

```
  <tbody>
  <tr v-for="(item, index) in fetch" :key="item.id_user">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.nik }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.nama }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.telp }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
    <td><button  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" @click.prevent="Hapus(item.id_user)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

 computed:{
    fetch(){
      return this.$store.state.pegawai
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["GetPegawai"]),
    Hapus(id) {
      if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
        this.$store
          .dispatch("delUser", id)
          .then((response) => {
            return response;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            return error
          });
      }
    },
  },
```

and my store

```
 mutations: {
    DELETE_USER(state, id) {
      const index = state.pegawai.indexOf(id);
      state.pegawai.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },

actions: {
    async delUser({ commit }, id) {
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(API + `users/hapus/${id}`)
          .then(response => {
            commit("DELETE_USER", id);
            resolve(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    },
  }
```

when I try to clear data, why is there no parameter for request?
[this like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMiQH.png)

causes the backend to not accept the id parameter

backend

```
 public function hapus_post(){
        $id = $this->post('id_user');
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
        $this->db->delete('users');
        $message = array(
                'status'     => true,
                'data'       => 'sukses'
        ); 
        $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Comment: The parameter is present in your screenshot as `26`.

Comment: true but the data is not deleted, if I use Postman, the data is successfully deleted

Comment: what headers should I use?

Comment: That sounds like a backend problem or with the way your front-end is sending the data, which differs from your Postman request. How is the backend expecting to receive the ID?

Comment: I've added my code above, check bro .. if in my post I use form-data to delete

Answer (score 0):

Your request currently sends the user ID in the URL, but the backend is expecting it as a data field named `id_user`.

Update your request to send the ID as data:

```js
axios.post(API + `users/hapus`, {
  data: {
    id_user: id
  }
})
```

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource ......

Comment: Adding data to the request wouldn't cause a CORS error, so the issue is something else. Can you link to a reproduction?